# How do I allow mobile users to bypass the redirect?

Tags: php, redirect, mobile

When a mobile user views my site they are redirected to a mobile version. I have a "view full" option to allow them to view the actual site instead. Problem is when they do they will get redirected back. Is there away to bypass the redirect or only redirect the first time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, almost all mobile browsers have basic cookie support. PHP `setcookie` ([documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)) will allow you to do something like this:

```
setcookie('default_view', MOBILE);
```

Where `MOBILE` is defined ahead of time. You're also free to use a string here.

The upside is you won't have to worry about the query string once this cookie is set. [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760312/how-do-i-allow-mobile-users-to-bypass-the-redirect/4760324#4760324)' solution will work, but you would have to pay attention to append `redirect=false` to every URL that has a redirect-checker.

Comment: the mobile devices are storing the cookie.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the question is. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I did it using sessions. I check HTTP_REFERER to see if our mobile address is in the address using strpos. If it is then I set a session value. As long as the session is still active they can use the full site. If they return to the mobile site the the session is destroyed. Works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a querysting such as `?redirect=false`.
Before redirecting, check for this querystring.

Comment: Is there a way to persist this query string (e.g., in server configuration files or something) so you don't have to refactor existing links?

Comment: @Steven: What would that mean?  (other than using cookies)

Comment: Well suppose the application code has a whole bunch of links back to the home page (let's say for now that redirection is only done on requests to the home page). Wouldn't you have to go back to all those links manually and add in `redirect=false` if the query string had been passed in on the request?

Comment: @Steven: Correct.  I don't know PHP or Apache; it might be possible to do that in an output filter.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to SLaks' answer, you could add a cookie 'redirect=false'. The advantage of this is, that you don't have to place the GET parameter on every link, so people stay on the normal page even after following internal links.

Comment: [COOKIES] Do not rely on cookies being available.
From http://www.w3.org/TR/mobile-bp/#d0e1925 
Many older mobile phones do not have cookies.

Comment: @Christa: True, that relying on cookies is not the best idea. But it works most of the time and is sufficiently easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I did it using sessions. I check HTTP_REFERER to see if our mobile address is in the address using strpos. If it is then I set a session value. As long as the session is still active they can use the full site. If they return to the mobile site the the session is destroyed. Works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you is using the database. When somebody enters your site write the IP of every user and also version of the site.

> |***_*__*_*** id ***_*__*_*__**|    site version  |
>
> | 88.75.125.xxx | normal |
>
> | 93.108.111.xxx | mobile |

When the user changes the version you can edit the proper id.

Comment: Mobile users are really often on a private network behind a proxy. Therefore you will have a lot of different users with the same IP...